# HTML/Shopify - How to make a 3 image carousel with one image on the left and 2 on the right stacked

Tags: html, css, shopify

Looking for some help. Needing a custom HTML that I can use for shopify that can make the layout of graphics look like this (sorry for quick MS paint job)

I've tried numerous codes on here and couldn't get anything to work how I'd like it

The text on the graphic is just the products are putting there, images will replace them.

Id like to be able to add links to each image.

This will be for a home page "Hero" or "Promotional Grid"

Thanks!

This is what I was able to find so far. Just no option to hyper link & add ALT text.

The   is there because i want the images to have some padding also, to fit the display.

The 3 images are; 3200x3200 and the other 2 are 3200x1200.

```
`<img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
.imgA1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
.imgB1 {
  z-index: 3;
}>

<img class="imgA1"
 src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>
&nbsp;

<img class="imgB1" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/filesXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">`
```

Comment: Can't see your MS paint job...

Comment: There are several things we can't see - have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to learn amongst other things how to show code.